# Displaying fields from Marshmallow schema during Serialization based on Request query params

Tags: python, flask, serialization

I have a request and response schema as follows.

```
from marshmallow import fields, Schema,

class TestRequestSchema(ma.Schema):
   fields_to_show = fields.List(fields.String(), required=True)

class TestResponseSchema(ma.Schema):
   id = fields.Integer()
   name = fields.String()
   status = fields.String()
   created_at = fields.DateTime(format="iso")
```

Now my api request has query params for fields_to_show where I can add fields name to get in my response(something similar to GraphQL). Is there a way to do display selective fields based on RequestSchema field values?

for example if fields_to_show = ["id", "created_at"] then my TestResponseSchema should serialize with only 2 fields: "id" and "created_at".

NOTE: Using GraphQL is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the schema's `only` attribute.

```
fields_to_show = ["id", "created_at"]
reponse_schema = YourMarshmallowSchema(only=fields_to_show)
```

Check out [Quotes API (Flask + SQLAlchemy)](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#quotes-api-flask-sqlalchemy). Instead of having a global version of `quote_schema` you could instantiate your schema within your request method and update your list `fields_to_show` from your query parameters.